# Add MySQL Rows In DataGridView and Customize How The Rows Are Imported

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

**What I Have So Far**: I'm working on my own basic program for practice. I have some vb.net code to import each row from my online MySQL into a DataGridView, which I can then print from.  However,  I'm running into an issue when customizing this.

**Issue**: I have each row in MySQL with a setup similar to this

Name | Date | Time1 | Person1| Person2 | Time2 | Person3 | Person4 | Time4 etc...

Once it adds "Name", "Date", "Time1", "Person1", and "Person2" I want it to move to the next line in my DataGridView and add "Time2" (under Time1) and "Person3" and "Person4" under their respective columns until it reads a new row from MySQL and then have it add everything again and repeat the process.  I hope I'm making this clear enough.  I feel like it is somewhat complicated for me to do and I do not even know where to start.  Not sure if it is easier creating a vb.net command to sort in the datagridview or maybe outputting it in SQL and then reading it.

The code I'm showing you below is my basic code that works for importing into my datagridview, but I need to somehow adjust that to do what I'm mentioning above.

```
    Using cn = New MySqlConnection("server=INFO HERE")
        cn.Open()

        Dim comm = New MySqlCommand(SQLCode, cn)

        Dim rowSearch = comm.ExecuteReader

        While rowSearch.Read()

            dgvPrint.Rows.Add(rowSearch(1).ToString, rowSearch(3).ToString, rowSearch(2).ToString, rowSearch(4).ToString, rowSearch(5).ToString)

        End While

        cn.Close()

    End Using
```

Hoping for it to look like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhsKQ.png)

SOLUTION:  (I was overthinking it for something simple)

```
While rowSearch.Read()

   dgvPrint.Rows.Add(rowSearch(1).ToString, rowSearch(2).ToString, rowSearch(3).ToString, rowSearch(4).ToString, rowSearch(5).ToString)

   dgvPrint.Rows.Add("", "", rowSearch(6).ToString, rowSearch(7).ToString, rowSearch(8).ToString)

End While
```

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate two fields while adding rows to gridview. Suppose Time1 and Time2 are 3rd and 6th Column respectively.

> *`rowSearch(2).ToString + "<br>" + rowSearch(5).ToString`*

```
Using cn = New MySqlConnection("server=INFO HERE")
        cn.Open()

        Dim comm = New MySqlCommand(SQLCode, cn)

        Dim rowSearch = comm.ExecuteReader

        While rowSearch.Read()

            dgvPrint.Rows.Add(rowSearch(2).ToString + "<br>" + rowSearch(5).ToString, rowSearch(1).ToString, rowSearch(3).ToString, rowSearch(2).ToString, rowSearch(4).ToString, rowSearch(5).ToString)

        End While

        cn.Close()

    End Using
```

Comment: If <br> doesn't work as expected, you could try vbcrlf.

Comment: Thanks Vicky! I will check this out.  Seems doable.  I will mark as the answer in a moment if it works.

Comment: rowsearch + vbcrlf + rowsearch enters it in the same cell and does not drop it down one.  when using + "<br>" + does not break the line but it just adds the string in the same cell as well.  thoughts?

Comment: **<br />**. Try luck with this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, nope.  using it in the same context as <br> but changing it to <br /> doesnt change anything.  still recognizes it as a string to insert in the same line.

Comment: I also added a screenshot example in the main description of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I misunderstood the question initially... My answer will not be helpful. Check the below link. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx

Comment: I was overthinking it.  This fixed it for me...  Added it in description.

Comment: Glad... It is I as well who was overthinking :P